# Why OpenMP runs only with one thread?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, openmp

I started to learnd MPI, and i try to run a simple MPI programm from VS Unit Test.

Version:Visual Studio 2017 (v141)
 Processor: Intel Core i3 CPU 540 @ 3.07GHz, 2 cores
 Everythin set to 64

```
 #include "stdafx.h"
#include "CppUnitTest.h"
#include <xmmintrin.h> // Contain the SSE compiler intrinsics
#include <intrin.h>
#include "mathutils.h"
#include "stringbilder.h"
#include <ctime>
#include <intrin.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <sstream>


using namespace Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework;
using namespace std;

namespace tensorlearn
{
    TEST_CLASS(noob_tutorials2) {

public:
    TEST_METHOD(OMP_HEllo)
    {
#ifdef _OPENMP
        if (_OPENMP >= 201107) {
            Logger::WriteMessage("Openmp supported");
        }
#endif

#pragma omp parallel num_threads(4)
        { stringstream ss;
        ss << "hello from MPI: thread " << omp_get_thread_num() <<
            " of " << omp_get_num_threads() << " \n";
        Logger::WriteMessage(ss.str().c_str());
                /* barrier and join*/
        }
        Logger::WriteMessage("barrier and join");
    }

    };
}
```

Howewer i got  like there is only one thread running:

```
hello from MPI: thread 0 of 1 
barrier and join
```

I checked the configuration of the project:

- in additional Include Directories:

  $(MSMPI_INC);$(MSMPI_INC)\x64;$(VCInstallDir)UnitTest\include;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)
- Enable Sdl Check and Multi-Processor compilation
- Linker additional dependencies : msmpi.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)
- Linked additional library dependencies $MSMPI_LIB64;$(VCInstallDir)UnitTest\lib;%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)

What can it cause - did i forget something, or maybe its because of starting from unit tests?
I launch it not from command promt but from the VS -> "run selected test", is that a problem?
Also ,_OPENMP is not set

Comment: first, you need to make sure the compiler was given the OpenMP flags. some OpenMP runtime requires some specific environment variables in order to perform `omp_set_num_threads()` (that could be a no-op otherwise). you also need to make sure the MPI tasks are not bound on one core, otherwise, even if you use 4 OpenMP threads, they would time share, which is helpless from a performance point of view.

Comment: i fordot to say, the CPU has 4 logical cores,  or that would no make performance gain?
The quesiton is, also  that _OPENMP is not set , since i do not get the printout about it, and because i m a newby and launch it via  VS "Run selected test" i do not know where the problem is.

Comment: it looks like you did not pass the OpenMP flag to the compiler. this is `-fopenmp` for GNU compilers, and i do not know what it is for visual-studio.

Comment: This has nothing to do with MPI. OpenMP is not MPI.

Comment: after setting compiler and linker, 
just found there is an option under right klick -> properties: 
 just checked : All options -> Open  MP Support  set to Yes (/openmp) nothing changes, still one thread